# Minecraft Earth Powers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm doing some command blocks to make earth powers in Minecraft, the first step for me is this command

```
/scoreboard objective add Earthling
```

Simple, Now I have an old answer for an assassin kit I did once, but it doesn't work when I swap it over. This is the command I want to work after it finds out who has the `Earthling` tag

```
/execute @a[tag=Earthling] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ air 0 /setblock ~ ~ ~ grass
```

Also, you must be wearing boots to make this work, [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288817/how-do-i-target-players-found-by-testfor) is what the guy who answered my assassin kit problem to do. If you can convert this to 1.12 command block logic for me so it will sense I have leather boots on I would be very happy.

Answer (score 2):

You will just need to add quotes around the

> minecraft:leather_boots

so it is:

> "minecraft:leather_boots"